# PhoneGap: Get a user's tweet without login

Tags: android, cordova, twitter

I am trying to build an App in PhoneGap for Android. I need to get a fix user's tweets via twitter and show all of his tweets. Means Tweets should be visible on app page not in twitter app or any browser.

I am trying to use twitter [plugin from here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Twitter). But i am not able to find how to fetch all of the tweets without authentication in this plugin.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: no, there is no error. Actually i din't find any way to authenticate the user and fetch his tweets. because it says that this plugin only have two functions and none of them is matching my requirements :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very simple, i was looking into wrong places, You don't need any twitter plugin for that, by implementing this code block in your html or any div or button click it'll get all the tweets and do the rest for you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
        <div id="twitter_update_list"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=SpinParty&include_rts=true&count=50&callback=twitterCallback2">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best suggested: http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application

One more suggest: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html

Comment: Thanks for answer brother, but as i asked i need to do this in PhoneGap